# How to make text Bold in TNewStaticText in inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

i want to get the text in TNewStaticText bold . is there any method available in inno setup

Comment: `StaticText.Font.Style := [fsBold]`, where `StaticText` is an instance of `TNewStaticText` class.

Comment: Hi,Can you please put a few examples of code which shows how to make the text bold in TNewStaticText

Comment: Oh, common. You've asked how to make a `TNewStaticText` bold, so I assume that you already have created some.

Comment: i am new to inno pascal . i don't much idea to make it happen. i need this as i have to highlight the text in the installer.

Comment: Well, but you can search. If you would search e.g. here on StackOverflow, it would surely return you a few results showing how to create a `TNewStaticText`.

Comment: Hi TLama, if you don't mind that i searched in google and i did not find how make text bold for TNewStaticText , can u please share some example?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/20VtDgZh

Comment: Hi TLama,Many Many Thanks for your post.I run your code and found the solution i was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome! Btw. I've turned my comments into an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bold text you can have if you include the `fsBold` style to the `Font.Style` property of your static text control, for instance:

```
[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  StaticText: TNewStaticText;
begin
  StaticText := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm);
  StaticText.Parent := WizardForm;
  StaticText.Left := 0;
  StaticText.Top := WizardForm.NextButton.Top;
  StaticText.Font.Style := [fsBold];
  StaticText.Caption := 'This is a bold text';
end;
```

Just out of curiosity, there are also other font styles that you can include to the `Font.Style` property. Here is the list of all the available styles:

- fsBold - the font is boldfaced
- fsItalic - the font is italicized
- fsUnderline - the font is underlined
- fsStrikeOut - the font is displayed with a horizontal line through it

These styles you can combine however you want, so for instance to make a bold underlined text control, you can set your `Font.Style` property this way:

```
StaticText.Font.Style := [fsBold, fsUnderline];
```