# Inno setup: Colouring Caption field

Tags: inno-setup

I'm trying to use this code [How to make text Bold in TNewStaticText in inno setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21730432/how-to-make-text-bold-in-tnewstatictext-in-inno-setup) to add it to this one:

```
procedure BackupCheckCreate();
begin
  BackupCheck:=TCheckBox.Create(WizardForm);
    with BackupCheck do
      begin
        Parent:=WizardForm.SelectDirPage;
        SetBounds(ScaleX(WizardForm.DirEdit.Left), ScaleY(WizardForm.DirEdit.Top + 135), ScaleX(WizardForm.DirEdit.Width), ScaleY(15));
        Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:BackupCheck}');
        Checked:=false;
      end;
end;
```

so that it colours with red the Caption field, but no luck, any idea or suggestion?

Thanks so much in advanced.

Comment: Check box caption text is rendered by the system theme. So even changing its `Font.Color` won't actually colorize the font. Either you would need to paint the whole control by yourself by subclassing it (which is quite a bunch of work), or e.g. add a static text beside the check box.

Comment: That is the other option I thought of, the problem is that I asked to show in SelectDirPage, but I got nothing.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. Did you ask how to colorize the check box caption, didn't you ? If so, then you would normally use `Font.Color` for that, but that caption is rendered by the system, so it won't make any change.

Comment: I do some tests and I'll tell you, thank you

Comment: There's no need to test. Setting `Font.Color` of your check box won't change its caption color. I'm sure about it. Easiest way you can follow is adding e.g. that static text beside the check box and colorize that static text.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do but I can't

Comment: Oh, now I understand. Well, then you have to narrow the check box in width otherwise it will cover your static text.

Comment: I have this code http://pastebin.com/7fMKMx2w but when I add to show it in SelectDirPage, it doesn't appear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64186/discussion-between-tlama-and-dexon).